# Which criteria is used by the linux kernel to pick udp source ports?

Tags: linux, ip, port, kernel, udp

They are all of course greater than 1024, but can we narrow this range a bit more?

Via wireshark the lowest I've seen is 30XXX. Does the kernel specify it's criteria somewhere?

Comment: Which kernel???

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify I meant the linux kernel.

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code ? This is where the answer is.

Comment: Somewhat related to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/341263/how-are-udp-source-ports-selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [ChrisInEdmonton](https://superuser.com/users/2649/chrisinedmonton) for pointing me to [this](https://serverfault.com/a/341271/240185) answer by [Jeff Strunk](https://serverfault.com/users/65472/jeff-strunk). Diving into the code included in the mentioned commit, I concluded that both **UDP and TCP source ports are chosen randomly between two values**. These values are modifiable in runtime, and can be accessed via sysctl:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range
```

On my laptop these values were `32768   61000` by default.